# CbQ webpart takes longer time to load, SQL slowness issue

Tags: 2007, development, web-part, performance

I have custom page and it has a CbQ webpart alone, it actually performs a query against a single list which has only 800 items with 15 columns but it takes 8secs to load. I suspect a slowness in SQL, how I can conclude that it is an issue with the SQL. Sometimes I could see the long running queries in the ULS log.

**Update**
The filter columns are used in the CbQ webpart are not indexed, will it impact the overall performance?

If so, howmany columns can be used for Indexing that should not affect the performance again? also, how can I eusure that Index is created for that site column?

Comment: one more doubt, what will happen if I have there CbQ in a page, is it all those 3 queries will execute Parallelly or one by one?

Comment: They are executed one by one

Answer (score 2):

It can be various issues that causes this. One way of getting a clue on whats going on is to enable developer dashboard.

See here for guidance on how to enable http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=189

Another option if you think this is SQL related, is to start up [SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx)

Comment: Do we have the developer dashboard option in SharePoint 2007? or is there any alternative way of doing it in SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Not that i know of. But try SQL Trace

Comment: From the SQL Trace, SQL does not take much time to complete the query..

Comment: Is the site generally slow? Are the db used for other purposes than SharePoint?

Comment: It is a shared physical machine with many SQL instances and ours is one of those..and it is just a PKS web-application which does not have data to be stored in the db..our DB size is ~1.5GB

Answer (score 1):

I would say the issue lies with the XSL rather than the SQL.

Do you have any custom XSL, and what data types are the 15 columns?

Comment: ok, will check the XSL & XML.  those are mostly text  and time field.

Comment: this is default XSL comes with the PKS for sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you think it is a SQL bottleneck, make sure you have object caching enabled.

Comment: we have already enabled the site collection object caching.

Comment: it is executing the CAML Query every time though we have enabled the site collection object caching. is that an expected behavior?

Comment: CQWP will cache the requests unless you disabled cahing in web part properties